# Convert a vfs url string to url object

Tags: java, jboss, protocols, vfs

In java i created a `virtual file system` url string (as a String object). But when i convert this String into `URL Object` i got `unknown protocol: vfs exception`. My java code looks like follows

```
String urlString = "vfs:/E:/Servers/jboss7/standalone/deployments/isms.war/WEB-INF/lib/aribaweb.jar/META-INF/aribaweb.properties";
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
```

and the exception looks like follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: vfs
    at java.net.URL.(URL.java:574)
    at java.net.URL.(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.(URL.java:413)
    at RegExpression.main(RegExpression.java:15)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, like doing this. The URL is invalid when we convert the `String` to `URL`. So, I think we can do this, like follows:

```
String urlString = "vfs:/E:/Servers/jboss7/standalone/deployments/isms.war/WEB-INF/lib/aribaweb.jar/META-INF/aribaweb.properties";
File file = new File(urlString);
URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
```

Like this. Don't show exception what you say.

Good luck